# knockout.js: does nesting result in resubscription?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Say, we have:

```
var model = {
    parent: ko.obervable({
        child: ko.observable('')
    })
};
```

When we call `model.parent(newParentValue)`, nested `child` is replacing with new one. Does it result `child`'s bindings will be unsubscribed from the replaced `child` and subscribed to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how literal I should take your question. For most intents and purposes the answer would be "yes", that is: the View will reflect changes recursively. You can check this in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9qJb/), that uses the following code:

```html
Child is currently:
<span data-bind="text: parent().child"></span>
<hr />
<button data-bind="click: setNewParent">Set New Parent With New Child</button>
```

With the following JS:

```
var model = {
    parent: ko.observable({
        child: ko.observable((new Date()).toTimeString())
    })
};

model.setNewParent = function() {
    model.parent({
        child: ko.observable((new Date()).toTimeString())
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

If you hit the button a new parent is set, and you will notice the view also updating the child.

If I take your question a bit more literal, there may be some fine details. For example, I don't know exactly what happens to the DOM elements. I imagine new ones are created for the new child, old ones may be discarded. In any case, for such detailed and literal questions I recommend looking directly at [the KO source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout).

Comment: Yes, we all can visually see new model nodes and new bindings are created. The main my doubt concerns old ones. So, yes, I mean the question literally, in particular, I'm very interested in the guess old bindings are completely cleaned up ("unsibscribed" in the initial question).

Comment: Have you tested your doubts yet?

Comment: As I mention the other option is to look at the source code, glancing over it I think [things are mostly cleaned up](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.domNodeDisposal.js), though you'll have to be more precise in your question if you want a more precise answer.